# mysql ERROR 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_MissingBooks`(p_UsrID BIGINT ,
      p_Product VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN


        DECLARE p_LinkedBoard INT;
        DECLARE p_LinkedSubjects INT;
        DECLARE p_LinkedClasses INT;
        DECLARE p_LinkedBoards INT;
        DECLARE p_SchoolBooks INT;

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO p_LinkedBoard
        FROM    userboards
        WHERE   userboards.usrid = p_UsrID;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO p_LinkedClasses
        FROM    userclasses
        WHERE   userclasses.UsrID = p_UsrID;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO p_LinkedSubjects
        FROM    usersubjects
        WHERE   usersubjects.usrid = p_UsrID;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO p_LinkedBoards
        FROM    schoolboards;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO p_SchoolBooks
        FROM    SchoolBooks;
        Select * From temp_MatchList;

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_MatchList(ID BIGINT ,
            Year INT ,
            Name NVARCHAR(100) ,
            SyllabusDisplayName NVARCHAR(100) ,
            BookType NVARCHAR(20) ,
            ClassName NVARCHAR(20) ,
            ClassID INT ,
            ClassNumber INT ,
            BookName NVARCHAR(100) ,
            Board NVARCHAR(100) ,
            Publisher NVARCHAR(100) ,
            SubjectName NVARCHAR(100) ,
            SubjectID INT ,
            BoardID INT ,
            STATUS CHAR(1) ,
            BoardStatus CHAR(1)
        );


    INSERT INTO temp_MatchList 
     SELECT * FROM 
     (
        SELECT vBooksDetails.* 
        FROM
        (
           SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
           (
              SELECT 
                classmaster.ClassID AS ClassID,
                CDisplayName,
                subjectmaster.id ,
                SubjectID, 
                subjectmaster.DispName ,
                BookName 
              FROM classmaster 
              JOIN subjectclasslinkage ON 
                 classmaster.ClassID = subjectclasslinkage.ClassNumber
             JOIN subjectmaster ON 
                 subjectclasslinkage.SubjectId = subjectmaster.id 
             LEFT JOIN 
              (
                 SELECT * FROM vBooksDetails 
                 WHERE 
                 (
                   (
                     (p_LinkedBoard = 0 ) OR (BoardID IN (SELECT boardname 
    FROM userboards WHERE userboards.usrid = p_UsrID ))) 
    AND ((p_LinkedBoards = 0 ) OR (BoardID IN (SELECT BoardID FROM schoolboards ))) 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM vBoardInfo WHERE ID = BoardID )AND vBooksDetails.Status = 'A'))
    lessonsyllabus ON subjectmaster.id = lessonsyllabus.SubjectID AND 
    lessonsyllabus.ClassID = classmaster.ClassID ) TAB WHERE TAB.BookName IS NULL ) TAB_MISSING 
    JOIN vBooksDetails ON TAB_MISSING.ClassID = vBooksDetails.ClassID 
    AND TAB_MISSING.SubjectID = vBooksDetails.SubjectID AND vBooksDetails.BoardID = 3 
    WHERE   vBooksDetails.Status = 'A' AND ((p_LinkedClasses = 0 ) 
    OR ( vBooksDetails.ClassID IN(SELECT classid FROM userclasses WHERE UsrID = p_UsrID ))) 
    AND (( p_LinkedSubjects = 0 ) OR (vBooksDetails.SubjectID IN (SELECT subjectid FROM usersubjects
    WHERE usrid = p_UsrID ))) 
        -- AND ((@LinkedBoard = 0) OR (BoardID IN (SELECT boardname FROM userboards WHERE usrid=@UsrID)) )
    AND ((p_SchoolBooks = 0 ) OR ( vBooksDetails.Id NOT IN ( SELECT BookID FROM SchoolBooks))));

END
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the part:

```
{...}
SELECT * FROM (SELECT vBooksDetails.* FROM
{...}
);
```

could have caused the error - the topmost select wasn't aliased.

Please try this version of your last big insert:

```
INSERT INTO 
    temp_MatchList
SELECT 
    vBooksDetails.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            classmaster.ClassID AS ClassID,
            CDisplayName,
            subjectmaster.id,
            SubjectID, 
            subjectmaster.DispName,
            BookName 
        FROM 
            classmaster 
            JOIN subjectclasslinkage 
                ON classmaster.ClassID = subjectclasslinkage.ClassNumber
            JOIN subjectmaster 
                ON subjectclasslinkage.SubjectId = subjectmaster.id 
            LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT * 
                FROM vBooksDetails 
                WHERE 
                (
                    ((p_LinkedBoard = 0 ) 
                      OR (BoardID IN (SELECT boardname FROM userboards WHERE userboards.usrid = p_UsrID ))) 
                    AND ((p_LinkedBoards = 0 ) OR (BoardID IN (SELECT BoardID FROM schoolboards ))) 
                    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM vBoardInfo WHERE ID = BoardID )
                    AND vBooksDetails.Status = 'A')
            ) lessonsyllabus 
            ON subjectmaster.id = lessonsyllabus.SubjectID 
               AND lessonsyllabus.ClassID = classmaster.ClassID 
    ) TAB 
    WHERE 
        TAB.BookName IS NULL 
) TAB_MISSING 
    JOIN vBooksDetails 
        ON TAB_MISSING.ClassID = vBooksDetails.ClassID 
           AND TAB_MISSING.SubjectID = vBooksDetails.SubjectID 
           AND vBooksDetails.BoardID = 3 
WHERE   
    vBooksDetails.Status = 'A' 
    AND ((p_LinkedClasses = 0 ) 
         OR ( vBooksDetails.ClassID IN (SELECT classid FROM userclasses WHERE UsrID = p_UsrID ))) 
    AND (( p_LinkedSubjects = 0 ) 
         OR (vBooksDetails.SubjectID IN (SELECT subjectid FROM usersubjects WHERE usrid = p_UsrID ))) 
-- AND ((@LinkedBoard = 0) OR (BoardID IN (SELECT boardname FROM userboards WHERE usrid=@UsrID)) )
    AND ((p_SchoolBooks = 0 ) 
         OR ( vBooksDetails.Id NOT IN ( SELECT BookID FROM SchoolBooks)));
```